# Uninstall libc6 (from Debian testing) from Debian stable

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, testing

I wanted to install the text editor Atom on Debian stable (but I don't want to anymore), and I had to install libc6 from Debian testing. Bad idea, I know. So I changed the sources.list, etc... Used this command to install:

```
apt-get install -t testing libc6
```

Then removed that line from sources.list. Now the System Settings won't run.

```
*** glibc detected *** gnome-control-center: free(): invalid poin
```

... and a very big list (of files?). The libc6 from this version (stable) is still on synaptic as installed.

How do I solve this? Is there a way to uninstall that libc6? Usually uninstalling packages with a lot of dependencies is not a good idea, right?